Tangent vector on smooth manifold using limit of sequence of points
I have a question from the book Introduction to differential Geometry of Joel W. Robbin and
Dietmar A. Salamon:
Let $M\subset\mathbb{R}^k$ be a smooth m-dimensional manifold and let $p_i$​ be a sequence of points in $M$ converging to a point $p\in M$. Let $\tau_i$ be a sequence of nonzero real numbers such that:
\begin{align*}
    \lim_{⁡i\to\infty}\tau_i=0,\quad\lim_{i\to 0}\dfrac{p_i-p}{\tau_i}.
\end{align*}
Prove that $v\in T_pM$.
I have tried the following approach: Construct a curve $\gamma\colon\mathbb{R}\rightarrow M$ such that $\gamma(\tau_i)=p_i$ for all $i\ne 0$ and $\gamma(\tau_{\infty})=p_\infty$. From this construction one could see that $\gamma$ is of class $C^1$ near $p$. From the definition of smooth submanifold, there exist a $M-$open subset $U$ (contains $p$) of $M$ and a smooth map $f\colon\mathbb{R}^k\to\mathbb{R}^{k-m}$ such that $U=f^{-1}(0)$. $U$ contains infinite many $p_i$ and therefore $\dot{\gamma}(0)\in\ker(df(p))$. Therefore
\begin{align*}
v=\lim_{i\to\infty}\dfrac{p_i-p}{\tau_i}=\dot{\gamma}(0)\in T_pM.
\end{align*}
I believe this approach miss sth important but I could not discover it. And why don't we define a tangent vector using this limit?

Do you mean $M \subset \mathbb R^k$?

Yes, I made a mistake in the notation $M \subset \mathbb{R}^k$.
